# Python moving a regular function with several lines to a lambda

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to learn python and Lambdas and anonymous functions but I'm having a bit problem with the syntax. What i want to do is convert this

```
def printer():
    print("hello")
    print("world")
```

to a lambda but i can't seem to get the syntax correctly.

Comment: `lambda` can only be one line. This is a feature that a lot of people have been asking for for a long time, but I doubt it would be added soon, since that would undermine the reason `lambda` was added in the first place

Comment: @Arandomcoder To be more exact, a lambda can only be a single *expression*, but it can span multiple lines. Although it is recommended that lambda is only used for rather small, non-complex expressions.

Comment: The reason you are struggling is that it shouldn't be done in the first place... This is NOT what `lambda`s are for...

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas can only contain a single expression, not a sequence of statements. They are intended for small functions that calculate a value. If your code goes beyonf that, it’s better to write a regular function, not a lambda.

Having said that, in your particular case you can do something like this:

```
printer = lambda: print("hello\nworld")
```

or:

```
printer = lambda: (
    print("hello"),
    print("world")
)
```

That would work, but it really doesn’t make much sense. The first lambda always returns None, the second returns a tuple of None (you would simply ignore these in your code when calling the lambda).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, and should not.

Yet if you really need you can some hack
like turning several lines into an equivalent single expression

`f = lambda x: print("Hello") or print("world")`